# DataFrame groupby hour and do the mean for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

Considering the following DataFrame

```
    Year    Month   Day Hour    1   2   4   5   6   7   Solar
0   2019    01  01  00  3856    6074    2123    3634    2219    2449    29
1   2019    01  01  00  3856    6072    2038    3443    2376    2644    29
2   2019    01  01  00  3862    6074    1916    3341    2734    2522    29
3   2019    01  01  00  3815    6074    1882    3135    2880    2556    29
4   2019    01  01  00  3751    6073    1855    3055    2940    2651    30
5   2019    01  01  00  3763    6071    1844    2978    2907    2628    29
6   2019    01  01  01  3808    6072    1842    2898    2868    2557    29
7   2019    01  01  01  3799    6074    1743    3559    2838    1844    29
8   2019    01  01  01  3810    6073    1688    3305    2766    1958    29
9   2019    01  01  01  3798    6075    1696    3142    2645    2048    30
10  2019    01  01  01  3740    6072    1678    3096    2598    2056    29
```

In order to get the mean of "Solar" (the 11th column) per Hour (the 3rd column), I have tried

1.

```
df['Solar_Mean'] = df.groupby(['Hour'])['Solar'].mean()
```

"Solar_Mean" will get only `nan`

```
    Solar_Mean
0   nan
1   nan
2   nan
3   nan
4   nan
5   nan
```

2. 

```
df['Solar_Mean'] = df.groupby(['Hour'])['Solar'].transform('mean')
```

Which gives

```
    Solar_Mean
0   272.4290164663996
1   272.4290164663996
2   272.4290164663996
3   272.4290164663996
4   272.4290164663996
5   272.4290164663996
```

3. 

```
df['Solar_Mean'] = df.groupby(['Hour'])['Solar'].transform(np.mean)
```

Which gives me the same as in the 2nd approach.

```
    Solar_Mean
0   272.4290164663996
1   272.4290164663996
2   272.4290164663996
3   272.4290164663996
4   272.4290164663996
5   272.4290164663996
```

As there are 6 files per hour, if one takes the sum of the first 6 files and divide them by 6, one gets `29.1666666667` which should be the right value. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not considering the `Year`, `Month` and `Day` when using the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). It should've been like this

```
df['Solar_Mean'] = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour'])['Solar'].transform('mean')
```

Which gives

```
    Solar_Mean
0   29.166666666666668
1   29.166666666666668
2   29.166666666666668
3   29.166666666666668
4   29.166666666666668
5   29.166666666666668
```